# Local nature of completion in an example of Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, local-rings

Hartshorne gives the example of completing the local ring of the affine variety defined by $y^2 - x^2 - x^3$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$ at $(0,0)$ on page 35. The takeaway seems to be that when we complete the local ring at $(0,0)$, we get a ring that is isomorphic to the local ring of the reducible algebraic set $S$ defined by the union of $y = x$ and $y = - x$, corresponding to the fact that in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$, the nodal curve $y^2 - x^2 - x^3$ "looks like" $S$.

**I'm confused because I don't see where the point $(0,0)$ is used in the argument.** Of course we are completing the local ring at this particular point, but in verifying that the completion is what Hartshorne claims it is, I don't think I've used any special properties about $(0,0)$ on the curve $y^2 - x^2 - x^3$, which should be necessary since the completion is capturing local information.

My argument that the completion is isomorphic to $k[[x,y]] / (y^2 - x^2 - x^3)$, is essentially: let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal in a Noetherian ring $R$. Then by properties of completion, since $0 \to (f) \to R \to R / (f) \to 0$ is exact, so is $0 \to \hat{f} \to \hat{R} \to \widehat{R / (f)} \to 0$. Thus $\widehat{R / (f)} \cong \hat{R} / \hat{f}$. Now $\hat{f} = f \hat{R}$ by considering both as coherent sequences of elements in $R$, and seeing that the coherence conditions on each give the same set of sequences, so we ahve that $\widehat{R / (f)} \cong \hat{R} / f \hat{R}$, and identifying $f$ with its image in $\hat{R}$, $\widehat{R / (f)} \cong \hat{R} / (f)$. Then we have that $\hat{R} \cong \widehat{R_\mathfrak{m}}$ by the argument [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64399/does-completion-commute-with-localization). So taking $\mathfrak{m} = (x,y)$, $R = k[x,y]$, and $f = y^2 - x^2 - x^3$, we get the desired result. Nothing in this argument seems to use any particular facts about the point $(0,0)$ or its maximal ideal, so why don't we get the result in Hartshorne that the local ring is isomorphic to the local ring of $S$ at $(0,0)$ for any point $P$ on $y^2 - x^2 - x^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point $(0,0)$ is used when you compute what the completion $\widehat{R}/(f)$ is. If you wanted to look at $(-1,0)$, you would consider $k[[(x+1),y]]/(y^2-x^2-x^3)$, which is isomorphic to $k[[y]]$ as follows: $y^2=x^3+x^2$ gives that $(x+1)=\frac{y^2}{x^2}$, so $(y^2-x^2-x^3)=((x+1)-\frac{y^2}{x^2})$ as $x=(x+1)-1$ is a unit in $k[[(x+1),y]]$ since it has nonzero constant term.

Comment: Letting $R = k[x,y]$, $\mathfrak{m}_1 = (x,y)$, and $\mathfrak{m}_2 = (x + 1, y)$, I had thought that since $\widehat{R_{\mathfrak{m}_1}} \cong \hat{R} \cong \widehat{R_{\mathfrak{m}_2}}$, we would get that both completions at $(0,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ are isomorphic to the completion of $k[x,y]$ modulo $(y^2 - x^2 - x^3)$, so $k[[x,y]]/(y^2 - x^2 - x^3)$, but I guess this is where I need to be more careful? How are you getting $k[[(x +1),y]]/(y^2 - x^2 - x^3)$ as the completion of the local ring at $(-1,0)$?

Comment: The isomorphism $\widehat{R_{m_1}}\cong\widehat{R_{m_2}}$ given by sending $x\mapsto x+1$ and $y\mapsto y$ doesn't preserve $y^2-x^2-x^3$, though. I'm getting the completion of the local ring at $(-1,0)$ the same way you are.

Comment: I see - I was thinking of that isomorphism coming from the inverse limit definition and some properties of localization, so the explicit maps were buried in too much abstraction. Thanks for pointing that out!